# How to index coordinates of elements in a matrix

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

I am drawing a two-dimensional matrix with vanilla JavaScript and CSS, but I'm struggling to index coordinates of every element.

There are a couple of problems. If I put coordinates in class, for example,

```
class="_1 _2"
```

And then use either getElementsByClassName or querySelector, I will get both elements with `class="_1 _2"` and `class="_2 _1"`

My current solution is to use both class and id. I then reference with `document.getElementsByClassName("_1")[1]`

I wonder if you have any thought/suggestion about this?

Thank you

Comment: why not `class="x1 y2"`

Comment: Is the matrix dimensions dynamic or static ?

Comment: AFAIK using underline at the start of a class name is 'normally' for vendor-specific or similar usage.

Comment: Have you considered [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)? e.g. `data-x="1" data-y="2"`

Comment: @pilchard yeah, that could be an option, but then I have to use regex to extract the number. I think data attribute as  Neea suggests should work.

Comment: @SahilRajpal supposedly dynamic, what would you suggest? Thanks

Comment: @AHaworth but I cann't use just number, can I?

Comment: @Neea yeah, that should works, thanks

Comment: Arguably by the time you’re querying with the numbers you already have them so I don’t see what extraction would be necessary, also any query with both x and y will only ever return a single element. This seems like an [xy problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: @pilchard I can give you an example. When I click an element, I can get the class name then I have to extract the number, right?

Comment: Fair enough, though that isn't part of you question. If that is your use case then data attributes seem the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess you could use data attributes like so:

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-x="2"][data-y="1"]');

for (let el of elements) {
    el.classList.add('selected');
}
```

```css
table td {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 2px;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

.selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-x="1" data-y="1">11</td>
    <td data-x="1" data-y="2">12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-x="2" data-y="1">21</td>
    <td data-x="2" data-y="2">22</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually want to give them all named classes?

It is sometimes easier to use the position of elements - nth-child(1) for example - in this sort of situation as they can be accessed via integer calculations rather than having to make a string (or two) to match the classes.

Here's a trivial example:

```js
function getEl(mx, row, column) {
  return mx.querySelector(':nth-child(' + (row - 1) * 2 + column + ')');
}
const matrix = document.querySelector('#matrix');
alert(getEl(matrix, 1, 2).innerHTML);
```

```css
#matrix div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="matrix">
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
  <div>D</div>
</div>
```

Comment: that's very interesting. I'm having a class row and a class column. Never thought about having all elements in one <div class="matrix">